# Doxygen doesn't generate documentation for enum not in class

Tags: c++, enums, doxygen

I have an enum inside of a namespace, but outside of a class. The enum is not being documented by Doxygen unless I enable `EXTRACT_ALL`, which extracts way too much unnecessary content.

The place where it's used doesn't link the enum (it does if I use `EXTRACT_ALL`). The enum and its members are documented (and the documentation shows up as expected with `EXTRACT_ALL`). Without that setting, the enum doesn't show up in the documentation anywhere.

Is there some other setting that I could use that would be more precise than using `EXTRACT_ALL`?

I currently have `EXTRACT_PRIVATE`, `EXTRACT_PACKAGE`, `EXTRACT_STATIC`, `EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES`, and `EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES` enabled, with the various `HIDE_*` settings being off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check to see if the file contains a `\file` command.

From the manual for `\file` (my emphasis) :

> The documentation of **global** functions, variables, typedefs, and **enums**
>   will only be included in the output if the file they are in is
>   documented as well.

See [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdfile).

Comment: If the enum is in a namespace you should document the namespace instead. Either by adding a special comment in front of one of the namespace blocks, or by putting a special comment with the \namespace command somewhere in the input.

Comment: This works in that the enum is included in the documentation, but for whatever reason, the class doesn't link to the enum type (it did with `EXTRACT_ALL`. Also, the enum's members aren't documented. With `EXTRACT_ALL`, the enum showed up on a namespace page (rather than a file page), so it may have something to do with that.

Comment: The lack of documentation for the enum is definitely related to the fact that it's global. Moving the enum into the class results in its members appears in the documentation (as expected).

Comment: Also, the namespace and file are both documented. The namespace pages just contain the "detailed description" (of the namespace) and no other content (like this enum).